# Run c# appication for all account users in same workstation

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-installer

I have created a deployment file`msi) using VS Setup project. This msi file create a shortcut in desktop. Application shortcut working fine i.e. it open the application and running fine while logged in as my account.

When I logged in as another account in my workstation. The application crashes and says "APP has stopped working".

I need to run the application for all account users

Any help would be appreciable!
Some one suggested to use non advertised shortcuts to install msi application. 
like Use of the command line switch for installation:

`msiexec /i APP.msi DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1`

It also throws same error when logged in another user.

Comment: You should figure out why it crashed - not finding a file? Not finding a registry entry? Some other reason?

Comment: Yes but it works for when login as my account.  How can I find the reason?

Comment: Run the application from the command prompt. You will see the stack trace.